# Is the story of Teth-Adam and the Seven Deadly Sins in Shazam! (2019) consistent with Black Adam (2022)?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, shazam-2019, black-adam-2022

In *Shazam!* (2019), Shazam (the wizard) described how Teth-Adam (Black Adam) released the Seven Deadly Sins into the world, and how the other wizards were slain by the Sins.

> **Shazam** (wizard)**:** But long ago, we chose a champion and we chose recklessly. He used his power for revenge, releasing the Seven Deadly Sins into your world.
> Millions of lives were lost. Entire civilizations erased from existence.

> **Shazam** (wizard)**:** My brothers and sisters were slain by the Sins. Their thrones lie empty.

In *Black Adam* (2022), as far as I remember, the Seven Deadly Sins weren't mentioned in dialogue nor shown. "Entire civilizations erased from existence [by the Sins]" also wasn't shown. It is also revealed that Teth-Adam killed the other wizards, and not the Sins.

> **Adrianna:** And the Council of Wizards was forced to deem you unworthy of the gifts that you were granted.
> **Shazam** (wizard)**:** We have chosen recklessly and humanity has paid the price. And now, Teth-Adam you must pay.

After the above dialogue, the wizards attempt to seal or imprison Teth-Adam using magic. Teth-Adam kills all the wizards except Shazam, who was able to successfully imprison Teth-Adam.

There seems to be some inconsistency on when and if Teth-Adam released the Seven Deadly Sins in *Black Adam*, and who killed Shazam's fellow wizards.

**Is the story of Teth-Adam and the Seven Deadly Sins in *Shazam!* consistent with *Black Adam*?** If yes, how are the apparent inconsistencies I've mentioned resolved?

Comment: Black Adam focused on how Teth-Adam ended up in the "present day".  There was very little of his "what he did to get imprisoned" story covered in the narrative.  What you're claiming as an inconsistency is, to my mind, simply as-yet-unoffered exposition.  I don't think anything from Black Adam contradicts anything that was presented in Shazam! (and given that they're definitely part of the same continuity, I'd be very surprised if there were a blatant contradiction), just that we haven't seen the whole story yet.

Comment: @CaptAlgorithm There was quite literally a scene where Black Adam kills all but Shazam in the movie. I would like to think that unless there was some really funky justifications like "the sins were offscreen helping" there is actually inconsistencies in narrative.